# First HelloWorld servlet with java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee

After doing all tutorial step by step, my first HelloWorld doesn't work like in tutorial. I have this error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pl.random.servlets.HelloWorldServlet

My files:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>pl.random.servlets.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HelloWorldServlet.java

```
package pl.random.servlets;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 102831973239L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("Hello World");

}}
```

and here my project explorer:

[image: descriptionImage]

Comment: Which tutorial did you use? Please post a link.

Comment: https://javastart.pl/static/jee/pierwszy-servlet-hello-world/